# How to know which scopes to exclude or to train when fine tuning a pre-trained model with TensorFlow slim?

Tags: python, tensorflow, resnet, pre-trained-model

I want to fine-tuning pre-trained resnet_v1_50 in TensorFlow slim with my own image dataset. But my dataset is not large enough to tuning the whole net. I want to see the scope names layer by layer then I can know which scopes to be exclude and which scopes to be trainable. Does anyone know a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

probably an answer now is too late. my self was looking for these things related to renet_v2 and "InceptionResnetV2/Logits,InceptionResnetV2/AuxLogits" these worked for me. you try changing the name here or if you can send me a link to the model, u can print the names using this code. just give the path to the model.

```
from tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint import print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
import os


checkpoint_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "pnasnet/model.ckpt")
# print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=checkpoint_path,all_tensors=False, tensor_name='')

reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(checkpoint_path)
items = []
items.append(reader.debug_string().decode("utf-8"))


with open('pnasnet/pnasnet.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in items:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
        print(item)
```